# Posting Blob Image using Ajax FormData

Tags: php, ajax, form-data

My data sends to the db without issue, but the "file" input posting my photo into my BLOB field in my db does not post. I receive an error.

My code looks like:

```
   $(function(){
   $('#Userform').submit(function(event){
     var fd = new FormData( $(this)[0] );
   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
         async: false,
         cache: true,
     data: fd,
     dataType: "text",
     url: 'mydburl.php',
        success: function(data){
        alert( data );
        alert('User successfully added');
     },
     error: function(){
        alert('There was an error adding New User');
     }
     });
     return false;
```

How would I append my data to include my photo "file" input? Any ideas would help. the name of my input is simply "photo". Without AJAX it posts fine when just sending to the form but because I am developing for devices, i need ajax to handle my form data. Any ideas would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try changing the content type to something like octet/application? or leave it away?

Comment: Yes. i tried application/octet but it made my form not function.Im receiving no errors in the console either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original answer was wrong. Editing now:

Try to remove the `dataType: "text"` line from your ajax request.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: Also, remove `cache: true` because you want to make sure nothing is cached in this case

Comment: Very close... i am now being presented with: <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: photo in <b>/data/24/3/17/29/3343681/user/3730590/htdocs/mypath/... this after removing cache: true and dataType: "text"

Comment: in PHP, the file uploads do not go into `$_POST`, if that's which array you're checking. Try reading the `$_FILES` array (http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)

Comment: yes i know, i have my photo posting using: $photo =($_FILES['photo']['name']); but still the same error.

Comment: if you inspect the HTTP request with FireBug or Chrome Inspector, what data do you see going to the server? You can choose "persist" data so the data doesn't get cleared as you investigate.

Comment: Im using Chrome inspector but i do not see an option for persist data!

Comment: I am being presented: Notice: Array to string conversion in /pathto/protected/dbInsertUserslocal.php on line 37

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51114/discussion-between-michael-butler-and-mizakita)

Comment: In chat, we were able to discover i had listed my name="photo[]" creating an array. This caused the errors. Thanks @MichaelButler you rock!